# How to handle importing a package import if it doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import re

import fitz  # requires fitz, PyMuPDF
import pdfrw
import subprocess
import os.path
import sys
from PIL import Image
```

In my case fitz doesn't exist since it needs PyMuPDF. Is there a way to tell python to download dependencies and install them if they don't exist?

I am new to python and learning a lot. Apologizes in advance

Using Python 3.9.4
Platform that I am developing on is macOS but will be deploying on Windows
Editor is VSCode

Comment: You can use a `try-catch` to handle it

Comment: try catch will not download the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `try-catch` to handle missing package

**Ex:**

```
import subprocess

def install(package):
    subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', package])

try:
    import fitz  # requires fitz, PyMuPDF
except:
    install('fitz')
```

A better practice would be to handle this before your code is executed. Example: using a `requirements.txt` file with all the dependent packages. And running the file before code execution.